# Quickest way to return each value of a property within a class

Tags: c#, linq, stringbuilder

I may be over-thinking this problem, but assuming the following class structure:

```
public class Car {
    public string Make {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}
    public string Year {get;set;}
}

List<Car> MyCarList = new List<Car>();

MyCarList.Add(new Car(
Make = "Honda",
Model = "Civic",
Year = "1997"
));

MyCarList.Add(new Car(
Make = "Ford",
Model = "Tarus",
Year = "2005"
));
```

What is the quickest way to go about combining each property for each element of `MyCarList`?

One solution I came up with was to overload the ToString() function in the class, and return each Element + Property Value - but that felt hacky.

One other (far less elegant) solution was to simply concatenate each property and build that out by hand.

The solution I was trying to come up with was using Lambda or LINQ, but the closest I got was only with one property of the class list.

I've also considered `StringBuilder`, but I wasn't sure if that would be a good choice for this problem.

The output would be used for logging purposes, and the concatenated values would look like this:

```
Make: Honda
Model: Civic
Year: 1997

Make: Ford
Model: Tarus
Year: 2005
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the concatenated value? Display it in error message, log it, show it in a UI? The _quickest_ way depends entirely on the context of what you're trying to do.

Comment: " the best way" is opinion based unless you specify very concrete criteria for "better". So far you got 3 answers solving completely different aspects of the problem in a ways that can't be even compared to each other...

Comment: @JSteward Please see edited answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry - I was more or less looking for a more clean/elegant/correct way to do this.  I know there are many ways to accomplish this problem, but one without using an external library for example would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another very simple approach is converting your object to a string with the [JSon.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.
It is just one line of code

```
var car = new Car
{
    Make = "Honda",
    Model = "Civic",
    Year = "1997"
};

string result  = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car);
Console.WriteLine(result); 

// output will be 
{"Make":"Honda","Model":"Civic","Year":"1997"}
```

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark your answer as correct - as it's the most elegant solution (even if it does use a library).  I was more or less looking for a possible alternative way to overloading the ToString() function.  If you were to suggest using StringBuilder - I would ask why (is it more efficient or just more overhead?).  Reflection seems slightly overkill as well.

Comment: Be careful with micro-optimizations. StringBuilder vs String has a long debate behind and the gain depends a lot over the quantity of data and its usage. When there is no clear problem of performance to solve I prefer to use a more clear and understandable code. Usually StringBuilder should be used when the strings to concatenate are a lot. Some background could be found searching for _StringBuilder Performance_

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using reflection. Check out [`Type.GetProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx):

Example:

```
var car = new Car
{
    Make = "Honda",
    Model = "Civic",
    Year = "1997"
};

var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (PropertyInfo info in car.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (builder.Length > 0)
    {
        builder.Append(", ");
    }

    var value = info.GetValue(car, null) ?? "null";
    builder.Append(info.Name);
    builder.Append(" = ");
    builder.Append(value);
}

Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString()); // "Make = Honda, Model = Civic, Year = 1997"
```

Comment: Why use reflection when you can simply write a ToString override that does the same exact thing?

Comment: Hold the phone, there's a better way to do this? I've been using this code for the longest time for debugging purposes, I would be interested in seeing this. Edit: @Steve can I get clarification on what you mean, are you saying to simply hardcode the values?

Comment: I mean, if the purpose is to get a string with all the properties values concatenated together for the Car class then just adding the override of ToString and writing a specific code that dumps the properties don't require the overhead of reflection. (or Json.NET as in my answer)

Comment: But JStewart above has asked the right question here.

Comment: I see, I misread your comment. The OP did mix "quickest" and "best" so it's hard to tell what he wants, but I felt my (quick and dirty) answer would be an appropriate starting point for him. (Also I hope I didn't come off sounding disingenuous in my previous comment, I was truly curious about it)

Comment: Anyway this solution is good for a generic method that works with first level properties of any class

Answer (score 0):

```
var props = typeof(Car).GetProperties();
var stb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var element in MyCarList)
{
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        stb.Append(prop.Name);
        stb.Append(": ");
        stb.Append(prop.GetValue(element));
        stb.AppendLine();
    }
    stb.AppendLine("--------------------------");
}
```

result.

```
Make: Honda
Model: Civic
Year: 1997
--------------------------
Make: Ford
Model: Tarus
Year: 2005
--------------------------
```